# I am failing to correct "Error 91: object variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on this for several days 14 hours a day and at my wits end. I have been reading hundreds of other posts.

I am a little above a beginner and have written successful code but not used "Find"

This should find a string and move it, then find the next instance in column "D", and Loop.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub a12sept230700()
      
    Dim button As Boolean
    Dim transs As String
    
    transs = ("Transactionss for*")
       
   ' endingxxx = "endingxxx"
    'endingyyy = "endingyyy"
       
    xxxloopnext:
   
    Dim transx As String
    Dim endingxxx As String
    Dim endingyyy As String
    Dim searchin As Range
    Dim searchina As Range
    Dim xxxloopnext As String

    Set searchin = Range("D1:D60")
    Set searchina = Range("D1")
    
    transx = ("Transactions for*")
    searchina = Range("D1:D60")


    'On Error GoTo 0
    'On Error Resume Next

        searchin.Find(What:=transx, After:=searchina, LookIn:=xlValues, _   
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    
           
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) = transx Then GoTo endofcolumna:
    
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) <> transx Then
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

        GoTo xxxloopnext
        
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Select = transx Then
        GoTo xxxloopnext
        
        
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("a1") = "transactions for *" Then
        GoTo xxxloopnext
        
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = "xxx" And ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("a1") = "endingxxx" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("a1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        GoTo endofcolumna
        End If
    endofcolumna:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Range("a1").Select
    
    totalsfor:
    End Sub
```

Here is a bit of the spread sheet...

[image]

I have tried dozens of objects variables etc.) .Find that I have tried is make one loop and error out...

it will search thru 600 rows and pull variable "transx" ="Transactions*" (xlpart) and cut it to "A" column and loop on till the "if" then
I find stackoverflow a great resource

Comment: What's the expected result? Move D1 to A1?

Answer (score 0):

The code relocates any cells in column D that begin with "Transactions for" over to column A.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range([D1], Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
        If UCase(c.Value) Like "TRANSACTIONS FOR*" Then
            Cells(c.Row, 1) = Cells(c.Row, 4)
            Cells(c.Row, 4).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Just a few thoughts. You can use `"D1"` instead of `[D1]` and you can use `"D"` instead of `4` or `"A"` instead of `1`. The `Like` operator compares case-sensitively (`A<>a`). `Cells(c.row, 4)` is the same as `c`.

Comment: I have updated the code with your last two points. "D1" works in the code snippet but I prefer to use `[D1]`. It is easy to used (eg. `ws.[D1]`) if the cell is not on activesheet.

Comment: OKAY!!! Thank you so much, I have made it overly complex and i have been studying this fo  most of the day yesterday and half the day today. I have been looking up the BYVAL MOVECOLUMN, LIKE, and FIND further.  Not only have you show me my errors. I have looked at formats and order, which answers some things in the past projects. I wish Microsoft had simple functional answers in their documentation. THANKS taller_ExcelHome..........

Comment: BTW I am using office 365 online version of Excel (2023)

Comment: Online Excel can't execute any VBA code. Are you looking for OfficeScript code instead of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

### Move Partially Matching Values

[image]

- The main issue with your code is that you failed to use the *Find* method correctly, in particular the *LookAt* argument, so it never found a match.

**Compact (Educational)**

```vb
Sub a12sept230700()
      
    ' Define constants.
    Const SEARCH_PATTERN As String = "Transactions for*" ' begins with!
    Const SEARCH_COLUMN As Long = 4
    Const ROW_OFFSET As Long = 0
    Const COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = -3
    
    ' Reference the whole range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    ' Reference the single-column range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = rg.Columns(SEARCH_COLUMN)
    
    ' Attempt to find a matching cell.
    ' A 'whole' ('LookAt:=xlWhole'), case-insensitive ('MatchCase:=False')
    ' search starting with the value ('LookIn:=xlValues') in the first cell
    ' ('After:=srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count)' & 'SearchDirection:=xlNext')
    ' is assumed.
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = srg.Find(What:=SEARCH_PATTERN, _
        After:=srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' To start the search in the first cell of a range, you need to supply
    ' the last cell to the 'After' argument. If you don't supply this parameter
    ' or you supply the first cell (default), the search begins 
    ' with the 2nd cell (it's irrelevant in this case).
    ' `LookAt` with `xlPart` means nothing else but 'contains'.
    ' To perform a wild card character search, 'xlWhole' must be used,
    ' e.g. "Begins with*", "*Ends with", "*Contains*", ... etc.
    ' 'SearchOrder' is irrelevant when searching in a single row or column.
    ' 'SearchDirection' is 'xlNext' by default.
    ' 'MatchCase' is 'False' by default.
    ' 'SearchFormat' is 'False' by default.
    
    ' Use 'FindNext' to continue searching with the same parameters
    ' previously set in 'Find'.
    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then ' a matching cell was found
        Do
            ' Copy only the value.
            sCell.Offset(ROW_OFFSET, COLUMN_OFFSET).Value = sCell.Value
            ' Clear the cell.
            sCell.Clear ' If you don't clear you'll end up in an endless loop!
            ' Attempt to find the next cell.
            Set sCell = srg.FindNext(After:=sCell)
        Loop Until sCell Is Nothing ' no cell was found (after a found cell)
        MsgBox "Cell values moved.", vbInformation
    Else ' no matching cell was found i.e. 'ElseIf sCell Is Nothing Then'
        MsgBox "No cell matching """ & SEARCH_PATTERN & """ was found.", _
            vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Argumented (An Improvement) - Main**

```
Sub ReArrangeData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange

    MoveColumnValues rg, "Transactions for*", 4, , -3, True
    'Or:
    'MoveColumnValues searchRange:=rg, SearchPattern:="Transactions for*", _
        SearchColumn:=4, ColumnOffset:=-3, ShowMessages:=True

End Sub
```

**Argumented (An Improvement) - A Method**

```vb
Sub MoveColumnValues( _
        ByVal searchRange As Range, _
        ByVal SearchPattern As String, _
        ByVal SearchColumn As Long, _
        Optional ByVal RowOffset As Long = 0, _
        Optional ByVal ColumnOffset As Long = 0, _
        Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Column Values"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If searchRange Is Nothing Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "No range supplied.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = searchRange.Columns(SearchColumn)
    
    Dim sCell As Range, dCell As Range
    
    Set sCell = srg.Find(What:=SearchPattern, _
        After:=srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not sCell Is Nothing Then ' a matching cell was found
        Do
            Set dCell = sCell.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)
            dCell.Value = sCell.Value
            sCell.Clear ' endless loop without it!
            Set sCell = srg.FindNext(After:=sCell)
        Loop Until sCell Is Nothing ' no cell was found (after a found cell)
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Cell values moved.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    Else ' no matching cell was found
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "No cell containing """ & SearchPattern & """ was found.", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If
        
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    If ShowMessages Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```